# Passing dictionary as parameter

Tags: c#, dictionary

> **The Setup**

Let's say you have the following code

```
public Dictionary<string,string> BuildSettings(){
    var result = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    result.Add("key1","value1");
    result.Add("key2","value2");
    //And so on...
    //Add a LOT more items to result

    return result;
}
```

> **The Question**

Because there are a lot of items in the dictionary, I want to split them up.
BUT... What is the "clean code" way of passing the dictionary to the submethods  (and returning it to the parent method)? What are the pros & cons from the options below?

> **Possible answers**

**OPTION 1**: Passing as parameter and returning dictionary

```
public Dictionary<string,string> BuildSettings(){
    var result = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    result = SubMethod1(result);
    result = SubMethod2(result);
    //And so on...

    return result;
}
public Dictionary<string,string> SubMethod1(Dictionary<string,string> result){
    result.Add("key1","value1");
    result.Add("key2","value2");
    //And so on...

    return result;
}
```

**OPTION 2**: Passing as parameter **--> MOST POPULAR ANSWER**

```
public Dictionary<string,string> BuildSettings(){
    var result = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    SubMethod1(result);
    SubMethod2(result);
    //And so on...

    return result;
}
public void SubMethod1(Dictionary<string,string> result){
    result.Add("key1","value1");
    result.Add("key2","value2");
    //And so on...
}
```

**OPTION 3**: Passing as parameter with "ref" to indicate a change in dictionary

```
public Dictionary<string,string> BuildSettings(){
    var result = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    SubMethod1(ref result);
    SubMethod2(ref result);
    //And so on...

    return result;
}

public void SubMethod1(ref Dictionary<string,string> result){
    result.Add("key1","value1");
    result.Add("key2","value2");
    //And so on...
}
```

**OPTION 4**: Return new instance of Dictionary and merge dictionaries

```
public Dictionary<string,string> BuildSettings(){
    var result = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    foreach(var pair in SubMethod1()){
        result.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
    foreach(var pair in SubMethod2()){
        result.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
    //And so on...

    return result;
}

public Dictionary<string,string> SubMethod1(){
    var result = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    result.Add("key1","value1");
    result.Add("key2","value2");
    //And so on...

    return result;
}
```

**OPTION 5**: Extension method

```
public Dictionary<string,string> BuildSettings(){
    var result = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    result.SubMethod1();
    result.SubMethod2();
    //And so on...

    return result;
}

public Dictionary<string,string> SubMethod1(this Dictionary<string,string> result){
    result.Add("key1","value1");
    result.Add("key2","value2");
    //And so on...

    return result;
}
```

**OPTION 6**: Dictionary as field in class

```
private Dictionary<string,string> _settings = new Dictionary<string,string>();

public Dictionary<string,string> BuildSettings(){

    SubMethod1();
    SubMethod2();
    //And so on...

    return settings;
}

public void SubMethod1(){
    settings.Add("key1","value1");
    settings.Add("key2","value2");
    //And so on...
}
```

**OPTION 7**: Other suggestions?

> **Result**

I think option 2 is best, like most people here indicate.
Additionally, I think adding a good method name could also help with this.

So this should be the code (in my opinion):

```
public Dictionary<string,string> BuildSettings(){
    var result = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    AddUserSettingsTo(result);
    AddCompanySettingsTo(result);
    //And so on...

    return result;
}

public void AddUserSettingsTo(Dictionary<string,string> result){
    result.Add("key1","value1");
    result.Add("key2","value2");
    //And so on...
}
```

Comment: Option 2 is the fastest and the cleanest way.

Comment: Option 2 and 3 are basically the same, since you aren't assigning to `result`. As such, Option 3 is a bit pointless.

Comment: For option 2, I feel like, that when other people will read the code, they could not expect that something would be changed inside the "result"

Comment: This question can´t be answered "correct" or "whrong", as it simply depends on your own preferences. There *are* differences between all those approaches, however it´s far too much to be posted in a simple answer.

Comment: `they could not expect that something would be changed inside the "result"` They certainly _could_ expect it. Whether they would is a different matter. Option 3 screams 'this parameter is going to be set', which it isn't - so breaks expectations moreso than Option 2 does.

Comment: ref in 3: that's a nice idea but instead I'd name the function to make it clear that it's going to add things.

Comment: Why can't you create a dictionary property in the class and use the same in all methods??

Comment: @rup no, it´s a bad idea as the keyword doesn´t exist for this purpose. `ref` means "change the **reference**". which OP obviously is not doing.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Agreed, I meant 'good that you're thinking about that' rather than 'yes do that'.

Answer (score 3):

If the key value pairs are all constants at compile time, you can just write them all into a JSON file:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", ...}
```

and use JSON.NET to convert it to a dictionary.

```
string jsonFile = File.ReadAllLines(...);
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonFile);
return dict; // you probably want to cache this. It may be to inefficient to read the file every time you call BuildSettings()
```

If the KVPs are not constants, option 2 in my opinion is the best-looking one. Alternatively, create extension methods for `Dictionary<string, string>` so you can do this:

```
result.AddBuildSettingsPart1();
result.AddBuildSettingsPart2();
result.AddBuildSettingsPart3();
```

Comment: Added the Extension method option to the list. (but in my opinion not the best way, since this will be applied to each dictionary

Comment: The keyvalue pairs are not constants and sometimes require some business logic to fill

Answer (score -3):

Just pass the interface as a param:

```
public Dictionary<string,string> BuildSettings(){
  var result = new Dictionary<string,string>();

  SubMethod1(result);
  SubMethod2(result);

  return result;
    }

public void SubMethod1(IDictionary<string,string> dictionary)
{
dictionary.Add("key1","value1");
dictionary.Add("key2","value2");
}
```

Comment: That's not the point of this question